# building small GUI engine: visible vs. addChild/removeChild

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, user-interface

Currently, i'm experimenting with a very simple GUI drawing ... "engine" (i guess you could call it that). The gist of it:

1. there is a FrontController that gets hit by user requests; each request has a **uid**
2. each **uid** (read "page") has a declaration of the components ("modules") that are present on it
3. components are **Sprite** subclasses and, in essence, are unique

Naturally, i need a way of hiding/showing these sprites. Currently, i have it pretty much like Flex has it by default - in the way "if we are in a place where the comp is visible, create it, cache it and reuse it every time it's visible again".

The question is - which would be the more appropriate and efficient way of hiding and showing - via `addChild`/`removeChild` or toggling `visible`.

The way i see it is that:

- `visible` is quick and dirty (on first tests)
- `visible` does not create a chain of bubbling events like `Event.ADDED` or `Event.REMOVED`
- invisible components don't get mouse events

So `removeChild` would be something i'd call when i'm sure, that the component will no longer be necessary on the screen (or the cache is too big, for instance)

What do stackoverflow'ers / AS3-crazed people think?

**Update**:
Here's a [good read](http://www.developria.com/2008/11/visible-false-versus-removechi.html) (forgot about google).

i will be sticking to `visible`; it seems to suit my task better; the manual "OPTIMIZING PERFORMANCE FOR THE FLASH PLATFORM" by Adobe on p. 69 gave me even more confidence.

here's a code snippet i put up to test things for those that are interested:

```
package 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.utils.getTimer;

/**
 * Simple benchmark to test alternatives for hiding and showing
 * DisplayObject.
 * 
 * Use:
 * <code>
 * new DisplayBM(stage);
 * </code>
 * 
 * Hit:
 * - "1" to addChild (note that hitting it 2 times is expensive; i think
 * this is because the player has to check whether or not the comp is
 * used elsewhere)
 * - "q" to removeChild (2 times in a row will throw an exception) 
 * - "2" to set visible to true
 * - "w" to set visible to false
 * 
 * @author Vasi Grigorash
 */    
public class DisplayBM{
    public function DisplayBM(stage:Stage){
        super();

        var insts:uint = 5000;
        var v:Vector.<Sprite> = new Vector.<Sprite>(insts);
        var i:Number = v.length, s:Sprite
        while (i--){
            s = new Sprite;
            s.graphics.beginFill(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF);
            s.graphics.drawRect(
                Math.random() * stage.stageWidth, 
                Math.random() * stage.stageHeight,
                10, 
                10
            );
            s.graphics.endFill();
            v[i] = s;
        }

        var store:Object = {};
        store[Event.ADDED] = null;
        store[Event.REMOVED] = null;
        var count:Function = function(e:Event):void{
            store[e.type]++;
        }
        var keydown:Function = function (e:KeyboardEvent):void{
            var key:String
            //clear event counts from last run
            for (key in store){
                store[key] = 0;
            }

            stage.addEventListener(Event.ADDED, count);
            stage.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED, count);

            var s0:uint = getTimer(), op:String;
            var i:Number = v.length;
            if (e.keyCode === Keyboard.NUMBER_1){
                op = 'addChild';
                while (i--){
                    stage.addChild(v[i]);
                }
            }
            if (e.keyCode === Keyboard.Q){
                op = 'removeChild';
                while (i--){
                    stage.removeChild(v[i]);
                }
            }
            if (e.keyCode === Keyboard.NUMBER_2){
                op = 'visibile';
                while (i--){
                    v[i].visible = true;
                }
            }
            if (e.keyCode === Keyboard.W){
                op = 'invisibile';
                while (i--){
                    v[i].visible = false;
                }
            }
            if (op){
                //format events
                var events:Array = [];
                for (key in store){
                    events.push(key + ' : ' + store[key])
                }

                trace(op + ' took ' + (getTimer() - s0) + ' ' + events.join(','));
            }

            stage.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED, count);
            stage.removeEventListener(Event.REMOVED, count);
        }

        //autodispatch
        stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keydown);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: If what I need to hide/show uses a lot of resources, typically I'll removeChild/addChild over settings its visibility. If its something minor or less complex like a graphic or text field, I'll set its visibility or alpha. It all depends on what it is you need to hide/show

Comment: @Ronnie removeChild only removes the item from the display list - nothing more.

Comment: sorry, I set it to null too and recreate when I need it

Comment: I never really put any thought into removeChild vs visible before, but one thing comes to mind. If it's still on stage IE visible=false then it might still be getting events/enterFrame not sure about it and not tested. It might be worth creating a test to see if enterframe still gets fired(I don't think it will) and see if any stage events are triggered.

Comment: @Ronnie if there is something that needs a lot of resources - it makes sense not to touch its display list and recreate it O-). Currently, I'm finding visual component creation to be the heaviest operation of all (although the comps are still quite simple).
@The_asMan `visible` does not affect `stage`. Because, `stage` is still there, i assume all stage-related listeners get fired. That is why besides setting `visible` i'm thinking about a function that (de)activates the particular component.

Comment: im referring to heave animations and such. Honestly, you probably aren't going to notice that big of a difference between the two unless like I said, something that is going to use the CPU heavily like say an onEnterFrame

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visible makes more sense to me (since removing a child indicates a finality) and is what I tend to use in my own projects when showing/hiding.

I'd also assume that addChild is slightly less performant but I haven't done any tests.

EDIT: I just came across this Adobe article http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/mobile/WS5d37564e2b3bb78e5247b9e212ea639b4d7-8000.html which specifies that when using GPU rendering mode just setting visible = false can have a performance impact since there is a cost for drawing overlapping objects (even though they are not visible). Instead, removing the child entirely is advised:

> Avoid overdrawing whenever possible. Overdrawing is layering multiple
>   graphical elements so that they obscure each other. Using the software
>   renderer, each pixel is drawn only once. Therefore, for software
>   rendering, the application incurs no performance penalty regardless
>   how many graphical elements are covering each other at that pixel
>   location. By contrast, the hardware renderer draws each pixel for each
>   element whether other elements obscure that region or not. If two
>   rectangles overlap each other, the hardware renderer draws the
>   overlapped region twice while the software renderer draws the region
>   only once.
>
> Therefore, on the desktop, which use the software renderer, you
>   typically do not notice a performance impact of overdraw. However,
>   many overlapping shapes can adversely affect performance on devices
>   using GPU rendering. A best practice is to remove objects from the
>   display list rather than hiding them.

Comment: This is what i tend to think as well. It's easier for the player to work in terms of "draw/not draw" than "add to display list, update the display list, spawn and bubble events, draw" and the way back. First simple tests (not unit test) show that the UI is more responsive when manipulating it via `visible`; i'll have to study it a bit more in depth though.

Answer (score 1):

Remove child is better to reduce instances,events and free up memory from your flash movie, You may find after time the sprites may effect each other.From how they are drawn or there listneres,Also Garbage collection generaly comes into play when this method is implemented wich can ultimatly screw around with your application

Visible still has the sprite in memory, its just currently not drawn.you could also save the sprite and then remove it, then reload it when needed would be an ideal over all solution.
using arrays to store data is another solution aswell depends on how your application is implemented, hard to say as we dont know ,lol

Adding the child performance i would say is less stress as its still only item adding vs multiples that are hidden.Also in these hidden children"s"  there properties are stored im memory along with listeners.

Comment: As noted by @Pixel Elephant - `removeChild` will not reduce your instances, it will remove references. If it happens that those are the only refs pointing to the object - they will be gc'ed and, thus, free up memory.
I haven't tested it thoroughly, but from the user's point of view - `visible` works faster than `addChild` and `removeChild`. No events are spawned either. Listeners can be unset along with the `visibility` (just like restored).

Comment: so your telling me if i was to creat a loop adding 500 objects to stage with listners,when they are invisible the listners just vanish?they are still referenced in memory until they are made visible again, but removing items will destroy all its assets from memory

Comment: not exactly; `removeChild` or `visible = false` on 500 objects - the listeners will still be there. The only difference in `visible = false` and `removeChilded` comp is that the first gets stage events; the second - doesn't. What i meant by "no events are spawned" - is that `invisible = false` does not spawn anything. `addChild` and `removeChild` - do spawn events.

Comment: If you are to truly destroy an object - you will have it remove all the listeners it has attached on external objects meaning any listeners that are NOT set via `this.addEventListener(...)`. If you don't do that, it will never get gc'ed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some hard data on the subject by Moock:
http://www.developria.com/2008/11/visible-false-versus-removechi.html

```
                  Children on the                     Single-frame 
                  Display List    .visible   .alpha   Elapsed Time (ms)
No Children       0               --         --       4
Non-visible       1000            false      1        4
Zero Alpha        1000            true       0        85
Fully Visible     1000            true       1        1498
90% Transparent   1000            true       .1       1997
```